# React Native Mapbox - Map overlaying other map on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, native, mapbox

I am using several Mapbox Mapviews in my React Native app. For iPhone everything works fine, but for Android the map on the frontview reappears as an overlay in another mapview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the react native repo at Mapbox.

There is currently an issue with the android implementation for `v5` of the repo, due to the React View not inheriting from the MapView and it is a huge undertaking to fix it. Luckily we are currently in the process rewriting the repo and I have already fixed this issue on our `v6` branch.

Depending on what features you need you could potentially start using the `v6` branch.

You can always pop in to our [gitter](https://gitter.im/react-native-mapbox-gl/Lobby?source=orgpage) chat room and I can help answer any questions for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nick! Great that this will be fixed in the v6! Do you have an estimate on when the branch will be released and ready?